# How do I combine several programs into one?

Tags: java

Say I want to combine two programs into one so that when I run the combined program, both of the outputs from the individual programs are printed. How do I write the code to accomplish this?

Program 1:

```
public class Number1 {

public static void main (String[] args){

    double s0=1.0;

    double v0=2.0;

    double a=9.8;

    double t=3.0;

    double s;

    System.out.println(s0+v0*t+0.5*a*t*t);

}

}
```

Program 2:

```
public class Number2 {

 public static void main (String[] args) {

    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){

        System.out.print(i*i + " ");

    }

        System.out.println(""); 

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply paste the code of your `Number2` class `main()` method code in `Number1`'s class `main()` method.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be to call the `static` methods of both classes `main`

```
public class Number3 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Number1.main(args);
        Number2.main(args);
    }
}
```

This assumes the `Number1` and `Number2` are within the classpath of `Number3` of course...

Comment: How does java determine which main() to call at startup?

Comment: @hyde You specify your main class in the `jar`s manifest file.

Comment: @hyde You can also specify the class Java should execute, in this case `Number3`...

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Number1 {

public static void main (String[] args){

    double s0=1.0;

    double v0=2.0;

    double a=9.8;

    double t=3.0;

    double s;

    System.out.println(s0+v0*t+0.5*a*t*t);
Number2.main(args);

}

}
```

If both the classes are in the same package then just call one main method of one of the class inside another class.Here I called main method of second class in first class

Answer (score 0):

You can write the whole code like this:

```
public class Combine {
    public void getFirstOne() {
        double s0 = 1.0;

        double v0 = 2.0;

        double a = 9.8;

        double t = 3.0;

        double s;

        System.out.println(s0 + v0 * t + 0.5 * a * t * t);
    }

    public void getSecondOne() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

            System.out.print(i * i + " ");

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Combine combine = new Combine();
        combine.getFirstOne();
        combine.getSecondOne();

    }

}
```